# How to randomly assign 9 cards to 9 predetermined locations without duplicates on code.org?

Tags: random, duplicates, game-engine, shuffle, code.org

I am a high school senior and For my computer science principles class we have to design and code a game as a final. I am trying to code one of those matching games (ex. http://mypuzzle.org/find-the-pair ). For the life of me I can not find out how to shuffle the cards so they change position every time you start the game. There are loads of tutorials on how to make these games but when I look at the code and none of it makes sense to me. As far as I know none of the tutorials use the same coding language as code.org.

[edit] Okay so I realized what I wrote above is vague and confusing. What I am really struggling with is figuring out how I can randomly assign the 9 cards to 9 predetermined locations, without duplicates, after they all converge to the middle, hence the shuffle.

This is a very basic game where the user needs to match 3 pairs of three to win. If anyone is feeling like an all star I also need help figuring out the scoring of the game. Thanks in advance to anyone who helps (:

```
var questionURL="question-mark.jpg";
var dogURL="dog.jpg";
var catURL = "cats.jpg";
var currentCard1URL = getImageURL("card1");
onEvent("Startbutton", "click", function() {
  setPosition("card1", 120, 216);
  setPosition("card2", 120, 216);
  setPosition("card3", 120, 216);
  setPosition("card4", 120, 216);
  setPosition("card5", 120, 216);
  setPosition("card6", 120, 216);
  setPosition("card7", 120, 216);
  setPosition("card8", 120, 216);
  setPosition("card9", 120, 216);
});
onEvent("Startbutton", "click", function() {
  timedLoop(1000, function() {
    if (currentCard1URL == dogURL) {
      setImageURL("card1", questionURL);
    }
    if (currentCard2URL == dogURL) {
      setImageURL("card2", questionURL);
    }
    if (currentCard3URL == dogURL) {
      setImageURL("card3", questionURL);
    }
    if (currentCard4URL == catURL) {
      setImageURL("card4", questionURL);
    }
    if (currentCard5URL == catURL) {
      setImageURL("card5", questionURL);
    }
    if (currentCard6URL == catURL) {
      setImageURL("card6", questionURL);
    }
    if (currentCard7URL == bunnyURL) {
      setImageURL("card7", questionURL);
    }
    if (currentCard8URL == bunnyURL) {
      setImageURL("card8", questionURL);
    }
    if (currentCard9URL == bunnyURL) {
      setImageURL("card9", questionURL);
    }
  });
});
onEvent("card1", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard1URL == dogURL) {
     setImageURL("card1", dogURL);
  } else {
     setImageURL("card1", questionURL);
  }
});
var currentCard2URL = getImageURL("card2");
onEvent("card2", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard2URL == dogURL) {
    setImageURL("card2", dogURL);
  } else {
    setImageURL("card2", questionURL);}
});
var currentCard3URL = getImageURL("card3");
onEvent("card3", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard3URL == dogURL) {
    setImageURL("card3", dogURL);
  } else {
    setImageURL("card3", questionURL);}
});
var currentCard4URL = getImageURL("card4");
onEvent("card4", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard4URL == catURL) {
    setImageURL("card4", catURL);
  } else {
    setImageURL("card4", questionURL);}
});
var currentCard5URL = getImageURL("card5");
onEvent("card5", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard5URL == catURL) {
    setImageURL("card5", catURL);
  } else {
    setImageURL("card5", questionURL);}
});
var currentCard6URL = getImageURL("card6");
onEvent("card6", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard6URL == catURL) {
    setImageURL("card6", catURL);
  } else {
    setImageURL("card6", questionURL);}
});
var bunnyURL = "baby.jpg";
var currentCard7URL = getImageURL("card7");
onEvent("card7", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard7URL == bunnyURL) {
    setImageURL("card7", bunnyURL);
  } else {
    setImageURL("card7", questionURL);}
});
var currentCard8URL = getImageURL("card8");
onEvent("card8", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard8URL == bunnyURL) {
    setImageURL("card8", bunnyURL);
  } else {
    setImageURL("card8", questionURL);}
});
var currentCard9URL = getImageURL("card9");
onEvent("card9", "click", function() {
  if (currentCard9URL == bunnyURL) {
    setImageURL("card9", bunnyURL);
  } else {
    setImageURL("card9", questionURL);}
});
onEvent("card1", "click", function() {
  var score = score + 1;
  setText("score", score);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Shuffling things, like cards is a known problem.  For a small set, like cards, then use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Other methods can be used for larger sets, but for 52 cards, Fisher-Yates is sufficient.

Some languages already have a `shuffle()` method built in, though for learning it is good to write your own at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a high school senior, and my final project is also to make a game. Although I think we're using different bases, you're using javascript like I am but you're referencing .png files, I use game lab so I don't really reference png files directly.

Anyway, personally I would create an array with each card possibility in it, then use Math.random(arrayLength) to pick a card, then place it, and remove it from the array, rinse and repeat until all cards are placed.

As for scoring, I'd use a couple variables. One variable to keep track of what pair you're working towards matching, then a variable for how many of that pair you've found in a row.

Considering you asked this 17 days ago, I don't know whether or not you still really need the help, but good luck!